# Exceeded limit of AWS S3 - how to change tier type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My AWS S3 Free Tier stopped working because I've exceeded a requests limit.

I understand it, but is there any way to change it for a paid type of S3?

It's sooo hard to find anything useful in AWS documentation...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS Free Tier is a **billing discount**. You still not be "stopped" from using anything, it's just a warning that you have consumed the free usage for the month.

By the way, the free tier is only actually worth:

- 5 GB of Standard Storage ($0.023 per GB)
- 20,000 Get Requests ($0.0004 per 1000)
- 2,000 Put Requests ($0.005 per 1000)

Value: **$0.13/month**
(`5*.023 + .0004*20 + .005 * 2 = 0.133`)

So, if you use twice as much as you are allowed in the Free Tier, you'll be billed 13c.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything. After your limit is exceed - you are starting to pay normally for the rest :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick answer!